# Mismatch berween output of javascript hex_hmac_md5 and python hmac.new

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, hash, md5

Using `hex_hmac_md5` in javascrpt from [here](http://pajhome.org.uk/crypt/md5/) :
For two strings 'hello', 'GOODBOY' :

```
hex_hmac_md5('hello', 'GOODBOY');
```

I'm getting : `c6554fe15f6de47df34c86b7a1014deb`

For the same strings in Python3, I'm getting different output : `bba9795b9ccb53871c31b776edcafe08`

```
import hmac
print( hmac.new( 'hello'.encode(), 'GOODBOY'.encode() ).hexdigest() )
```

What changes do I need to make in python code to return `c6554fe15f6de47df34c86b7a1014deb` ?

Comment: Why do you need compatibility with some random niche library? There are many libraries that are much better documented.

Comment: My main goal is to get the same hash (which I got using javascript hex_hmac_md5 ) using any python library.

Comment: Figure out what the library does internally and which format it expects its inputs in. This might be an encoding issue, but it could also mean that the JS library is incorrectly implemented.